# Interop Crypto OpenSslCryptographicException: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: .net-core, tcpclient, sslstream

No matter target to `net5.0` or `net6.0` framework, when trying to create a `sslstream`, it repeatedly throw the error running on **Ubuntu** OS while works on **Windows** OS, what's the proper way to handle this error ?

### Error Message

```cs
 System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
       ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
       ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
```

### Sample Code

```cs
public static SslStream CreateSslStream(this TcpClient client, bool leaveInnerStreamOpen = false)
{
    var validationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
    var selectionCallback = new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(SelectLocalCertificate);
    return new SslStream(client.GetStream(), leaveInnerStreamOpen, validationCallback, selectionCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I referenced the ticket: [Reopen #44191: SSL/TLS handshake fails in Ubuntu 20.04 and Net 5.0.1](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46271), making a custom `openssl.cnf`, now the problem is got resolved.

### /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

```
# Add this in the head of the file
openssl_conf = openssl_init

#
# skip
#

# And the following in the end of the file
[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_config

[ssl_config]
system_default = tls_defaults

[tls_defaults]
CipherString = @SECLEVEL=2:kEECDH:kRSA:kEDH:kPSK:kDHEPSK:kECDHEPSK:-aDSS:-3DES:!DES:!RC4:!RC2:!IDEA:-SEED:!eNULL:!aNULL:!MD5:-SHA384:-CAMELLIA:-ARIA:-AESCCM8
Ciphersuites = TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
```

Comment: I do not have file there!

Comment: this [link](https://exampleconfig.com/view/openssl-ubuntu20-04-etc-ssl-openssl-cnf) might help you